# How to make start with / contains work with EF and SQL Text column storing JSON

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have table with nvarchar (max) column storing json like one below,

> {"status":"Archieved","oldCategories":{"name":"LONG Life -
>   Milk","products":{"tagPrice1Notes":"800 Times
>   Said","columnType2":"","columnType3":"someValue3","columnType4":"someValue4","columnType5":"someValue5","columnType6":"someValue6","columnType7":"someValue7"}},"moreProperties":.... so on

Now I need to get all columns where value starts with above string, however I am getting 0 rows back, here is what I am trying,

```
 var matchMe = (
                "{'status':'Archieved'" +
                "','oldCategories': {'name': '" + someObject.Name +
                "','products': {'tagPrice1Notes': '" + someObject.C1 +
                "','columnType2': '" + someObject.C2 +
                "','columnType3': '" + someObject.C3 +
                "','columnType4': '" + someObject.C4 +
                "','columnType5': '" + someObject.C5 +
                "','columnType6': '" + someObject.C6 +
                "','columnType7': '" + someObject.C7 +
                "'}}"
                );
dbContext.CategoriesProducts.Where(x => x.MyJsonDetailsColumn.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(matchMe.ToUpper().Trim()))
.ToList();
```

This is a temporary fix and we will do a refactor later on.

Comment: The text uses double quotes, but your code uses single e.g. `"status"` / `'status'`.

Comment: Check your spelling.   'Archieved' - is that spelt wrong in the data, or could it be Archived, or Achieved ?

Comment: Also, your query has spaces between fieldname and value, which the example does not.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem like a good approach. Comparing custom-built JSON against DB is error-prone (like extra space) and it will quickly become really slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code will basically read all the data back to your client (the ToUpper/Trim parts will mean this is a client side check), so why not just read all the data, deserialise it into an object and perform a proper comparison of the fields you need to?

Comment: won't deserialising going to take more time, let say for 2000 rows for now, searching vs deserializing

Comment: 2000 rows is not really very much data.  If you are worried, then measure it, but I doubt it's that bad. You say yourself this is a temporary fix.

Comment: It's going to be much faster than pulling the whole table to the client and then looking through a string. Or searching the string using full-text index. This proposed solution is clean, easy and you won't have a hassle finding extra/missing space, quote, comma, etc.